# Debian system can't access full memory

Tags: debian, installation, memory-management, dualboot

I decided to install Linux debian 12 on my PC today. The install itself worked without issues, but I am unable to install applications. When I try to the system tells me to re-enter the drive.

In the filemanager it also doesn't show the complete m.2, so I think the system might not have access to it but I don't know why.

As a little bit of background: I installed it as a dual boot system, I have one 128gb SSD that contains win11 and installed dabian on the 2tb m.2
As I installed debian I selected the m.2 and chose automatic partition.

I would be great full for any suggestions.

Comment: would be great if yo showed some meaningful info, like the partitioning of the devices for example - I guess by "memory" you don't mean RAM, you mean disk drives `In the filemanager it also doesn't show the complete m.2` - what does it show? what were you expecting instead?

Comment: `system tells me to re-enter the drive` could you describe this a little more accurately? I'm sure the message is not "re-enter the drive" as that suggests 1. you did enter the drive (whatever that means) and 2. you must now re-enter it for apparently no reason at all

Comment: The file manager only shows 128GB of memory.                                               
Running lsblk returns:                                                                                         
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda1        8:1    0    16M  0 part 
└─sda2        8:2    0 119,2G  0 part /media/maysen/80F81291F8128596
nvme0n1     259:0    0   1,9T  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0   1,9T  0 part /
└─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   977M  0 part [SWAP]

Comment: My system is in german so the exact message probably wont be helpfull, the translated message however is: Media change: Please insert the media with the name
»Debian GNU/Linux 12.2.0 _Bookworm_ - Official amd64 DVD Binary-1 with firmware 20231007-10:29«
in the drive “/media/cdrom/” and press the Enter key.

Comment: oh that's simple then. That's just because your system thinks there's a CDROM source for packages. Simply remove that  and run an apt update

Comment: according to that lsblk, nvme0n1p2 on / is 1.9TB so not sure what "file manager" you're talking about - what does `df -h /` output

Comment: Thank you so much, everything seems to work after having removed it.